# Supervisord not autorestarting exited process

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, supervisord

I have a PHP script which I am spawning (succesfully) using supervisord:

```
2012-06-29 12:45:15,266 INFO spawned: 'tvm' with pid 4395
2012-06-29 12:45:16,455 INFO success: tvm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2012-06-29 12:45:18,218 INFO exited: tvm (exit status 0; expected)
```

However, when the script exits, it doesn't respawn despite having set autorestart=true in the supervisord.conf

```
[program:tvm]
command=php /var/www/transcodedvideomonitor/index.php ;
autorestart=true ;
```

What have I missed?

Comment: *Long shot*: What version of supervisord are you using? `autorestart` wasn't introduced until 3.0.

Comment: It's 3.0a12. I tried removing the semi-colons as suggested elsewhere but that still didn't do the trick. I've now resorted to using the inotify-tools.

Comment: I suggested the semicolons, here on SO as an answer, before I realized that they are parsed as comments and thus couldn't be the cause. Sorry things didn't work for you!

Comment: It's OK, thanks for trying to helping Martijn :) I modified a PHP script so that it uses inotify (http://php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php) and lsof and it works a treat.